# How to derive direction cosines in spherical coordinates?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How to derive direction cosines in spherical coordinates? What $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ mean? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Can't you deduce the answer by looking at the equations?

Comment: I can't, can you please explain it to me?

Comment: If $r\cos\phi\sin\theta=r\lambda$ then $\lambda = ...$?

Comment: $\lambda = \cos\phi sin\theta  $ but what is the interpretation of this variable?

Comment: Interesting. If I have the direction cosines and $r$, how would I find $x$?

Comment: OK, thank you, I see.